# How to render a Scene in JavaFX? (2D Game)

Tags: javafx

I have to create a 2D rpg game for my project. In nearly every tutorial I read, they used canvas for drawing the Scene and it was possible with canvas to render the Scene.

Is there any way to  render the Scene without canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX has AnimationTimer, which is equivalent of drawing/updating a scene using canvas in Swing. This allows you to handle sprite movement and animations smoothly.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html

Also, here is a good JavaFX game tutorial.  It isn't an RPG game tutorial, but you can take a lot of information from the code, how AnimationTimer is used, and the overall structure of a game using JavaFX:
http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: Thanks i did not know, that AnimationTimer is so powerfull :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :)